# context in object class. why it is memory leak?

Tags: kotlin

when I use object class with context, it shows warnning "do not use context in static field".
I wanna know why I have not to do that?

```
object Auth {

     var mContext : Context ?= null

}
```

Comment: Because you'll keep a reference to an Activity class which android might destroy.

Comment: thank you I understand